# get Container.ItemIndex in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I want to use `Container.ItemIndex` in my Code Behind in my function in `OnCustomColumnDisplayText` event in C#. Now I have `dxwgv:ASPxGridView` with `OnCustomColumnDisplayText`, where I have:

```
<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn
    FieldName="PlainQuestion"
    VisibleIndex="1"
    Width="90%"
    Caption="Question">
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <%#Container.ItemIndex+1%>.  <%#Container.Text %>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

So, I need to use it in Code Behind.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the *VisibleRowIndex* property of the *ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs* of your *CustomColumnDisplayText* event handler

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic